# Can EntityFramework Core 6 process xml data returned from a stored procedure

Tags: xml, entity-framework-core

Good Day,

I use Entity Framework Core 6.0 to process Stored Procedures from a SQL Server 2019 server and one of the procedures returns an XML document as a result similar to this:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Base>
    <Id>3022345</Id>
    <Name>John Smith</Name>
    <Age>11</Age>
    <Hobbies>
      <Hobby>
        <Name>Tennis</Name>
        <MatchesWon>2</MatchesWon>
        <MatchesLost>0</MatchesLost>
     </Hobby>
    </Hobbies>
  </Base>
  <Base>
    <Id>11234</Id>
    <Name>Jane Dough</Name>
    <Age>50</Age>
    <Hobbies>
      <Hobby>
        <Name>VolleyBall</Name>
        <MatchesWon>30</MatchesWon>
        <MatchesLost>19</MatchesLost>
     </Hobby>
      <Hobby>
        <Name>Bowling</Name>
        <MatchesWon>44</MatchesWon>
        <MatchesLost>32</MatchesLost>
     </Hobby>
    </Hobbies>
  </Base>
<Root>
```

And I cannot seem to find a way to process this using the standard DbDataReader that gets returned from the call.

Has anyone ever tried reading / processing an XML result?

Thank you,
T

Comment: Show some code how you use EF to process SP.

Comment: Add language tag. Specify your DBMS.

Answer (score -1):

Try following.  You are using Entity and the c# classes have to be consistent with the database.  You shou

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            //get resposne and put into a string reader
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader (xml);

            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            Root root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
            
 
        }
    }
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("Base")]
        public List<Base_Response> baseResponse { get; set; }
    }
    public class Base_Response
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Hobbies")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Hobby")]
        public List<Hobby> Hoby { get; set; }
    }
    public class Hobby
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int MatchesWone { get; set; }
        public int MatchesLost { get; set; }
    }
 
}
```

ld be able to get a string from the DbReader and the deserialize using following :

Comment: IMHO, this answer has nothing to do with "xml from a STORED PROCEDURE".  Please delete or edit.

Comment: @granadaCoder : Entity requires the classes and the classes are fully tested.  You can use Code first approach with my classes.